# How should we get comics tags used more often?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was looking for a question I had hoped to be able to answer, and I tried searching using the [comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics) but it turns out that didn't bring up the question. I instead searched for [avengers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers) and found a load of incorrectly tagged questions (ignoring the ones that are for the recent movie), in so much that they didn't contain the comics tag, just the Marvel-comics tag, or just the character featured.

Going through and retagging all the questions would be awesome, but surely we can do something to prevent this atrocity?

Comment: Could we have some dicussion over the downvotes? Do people not think this is an issue?

Answer (score 2):

Both [How should marvel-comics and DC-comics be used?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/how-should-marvel-comics-and-dc-comics-be-used?rq=1) and [Should the marvel/DC-comics tag be changed to just marvel/DC?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1706/should-the-marvel-dc-comics-tag-be-changed-to-just-marvel-dc?rq=1) mention changing the [marvel-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-comics) and [dc-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-comics) tags to be just [marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel) and [dc](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc), then using [comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics)/[movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie) to distinguish between questions on the comics versus questions on the movies.

If that was a consensus approach (applied to the existing questions as well) it would solve your issue.

I suspect we're going to see this same problem with DC when the next Superman movie comes out unless a change is made.

Answer (score 1):

I personally do not use the [comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics) tag unless I am talking about comics in general, or I'm not using the [dc-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-comics) or [marvel-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-comics) tags.

It feels redundant to tag something with [comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics) if it is already set as [dc-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-comics).

Is it possible for a tag to be an alias for multiple tags? So that choosing [comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics) would bring up both dc and marvel (and all others) ?

Comment: The issue is that as Marvel Comics is the correct name for the trading company, tagging with say [tag:marvel-comics] and [tag:avengers] brings up questions about the movie, more than the comic books. Which is unhelpful. Perhaps it's this attitude that's giving us a lack of Comics tagged questions?

Comment: I think the issue is that the huge popularity of the Marvel films has skewed the meaning of [tag:marvel-comics] towards the films, where it used to be more comic-centric.  [tag:dc-comics] doesn't quite suffer from the same issue (yet).

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative is to leave the company tags as is, but create tags like [avengers-movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers-movie), [xmen-movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xmen-movie), [superman-movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superman-movie), etc etc etc to disambiguate these.

Comment: That is an alternative, but then what if people are searching for just X-men, wanting comics and movies? I don't think it'd help.