# How should we tag Marvel and DC as a whole, considering how we've done so?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently we have [marvel-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-comics)/[marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel) and [dc-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-comics)/[dc](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc) which are the franchise-level tags that are equivalent to [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter), [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek), and [tolkien-legendarium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien-legendarium). [Old-school policy suggested](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1521/31178) we use them on pretty much any question regarding properties put out by those publishers, and then add the sub-tags like [x-men](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men) as necessary. That's how we generally do things with most properties, today.

However, there's a major lack of use of these tags, particularly when it comes to some of the publisher's biggest properties:

- Superman has only [161 questions tagged with DC](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superman+dc-comics) vs [235 without](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superman+-dc-comics)
- Batman has only [192 questions tagged with DC](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman+dc-comics) vs [266 without](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman+-dc-comics)
- Avengers has only [118 questions tagged with Marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers+marvel-comics) vs [183 without](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers+-marvel-comics)
- Thor has only [81 questions tagged with Marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thor+marvel-comics) vs [102 without](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thor+-marvel-comics)
- X-Men has only [189 questions tagged with Marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men+marvel-comics) vs [267 without](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men+-marvel-comics)

The list goes on. Basically, all of the tags big enough to be easily seen on our tag map have this problem, where > 50% of the tags are missing the publisher franchise tag.

[Map of all 2,355 tags](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9522/map-of-all-2-137-tags)

What should we do about these tags, or how should we be using them?

Is it even necessary to tag [batman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman) with [dc-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-comics)? Should we make exceptions for the major franchises from those studios? If so, which tags/characters should be considered their own top-level franchise tags?

Also keep in mind that we have collective work tags such as [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe), [dc-extended-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-extended-universe), and [dcau](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dcau).

---

Keep in mind, retroactive fixes are rare. The new frontpage that will be launched soon *may* change things, and this weekend is an exception, but I'm not asking necessarily how to fix the problems we have now all at once. Instead, I'm wondering about **a policy for all future questions** and a way to make trickling edits as the opportunities organically develop over time. **Leave it be isn't an answer** because what we're doing right now is apparently worse than flipping a coin to decide whether or not to apply the tags.

Comment: **Just a note**: It took me maybe 15 minutes to do about 200 tag edits for Tolkien tags (and I'm still going), so if we had a strong response ASAP, it's actually not unreasonable to get this taken care of now during the current event, especially if we're just going to follow the existing policy of "Everything gets it."

Answer (score 9):

## Make em consistent.

Let's retag all of the questions without the tags to keep it consistent with how we do the other tags. We can lump them in the Big Edit Event.

This means that all of the media and characters get the tag for the parent publisher. i.e., all [superman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superman) questions get [dc](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc), all [avengers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers) get [marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel) .

Comment: Please elaborate on this answer. What tags are you suggesting adding to what questions?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - better now?

Comment: A bit. Still could be a bit clearer: are you proposing that all questions about any DC comics get the [tag:dc-comics] tag? Many [tag:superman] questions are going to be about films and not comics; do you also want those to have the comics tag?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - yes, all DC comics get the tag. I don't know about the movies; I'll think about it.

Comment: @Randal'Thor The `-comics` tag is just the name of the publisher, they're both synonyms with the same tag sans -comics

Comment: So perhaps separate the tags so that they're no longer synonymous? I.e have "DC" and "Marvel" represent the publishers and "DC-Comics" and "Marvel-Comics" represent purely the comic medium. If we have separate tags for the cinematic universes, we should have tags for the comics as well. I don't expect direct current to get much in-depth discussion on this site, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo - oof. We're already having problems with the 5-tag-limit on comics questions; do we *really* need to add another?

Comment: @DisturbedNeo There's historically been no need for that. _If_ and only if a user says "I only want comic-book based answers" we add the `comics` tag if there's room, to specify scope. However, if you are meaning to say names of individual comics such as `the-superior-spider-man`, then yes, that run/series _can_ get its own tag but generally unless it's about a graphic novel (see `dark-knight-returns`) people are just asking about the character in general, across all continuities. Although, another exception, we do have `the-new-52`.